# How to set path to python (venv) executable in atom editor

Tags: python, virtualenv, atom-editor

I'm trying to switch to Atom Editor for my python projects. I have several of those and each is set up using `virtualenv`.

How do I set up this editor, so that when I open up one project it will be using `python.exe` from its path and not some other?

I don't want to add anything to the `init script` because, as far as I understand, this script contains global settings. Is there a way to configure the desired behavior 'per project'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that python-autocomplete plugin is all we need in atom python coding. Just set your virtualenv from the console, then type `atom .` and editor (accompanied with aforementioned plugin) will pick that up. No other configuration is necessary.